# Docker: Nginx Reverse Proxy returns error 504 when trying to host multiple site in 1 VPS

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to host multiple sites using docker in one VPS. I want that each site will have 1 nginx server and 1 php and all the sites will have 1 common mysql database.

This is how containers looks like:

mysql_container (port: 3306)

main_webserver (nginx container) (port 80)

site_1 (site.com)
 - nginx container (81:80), php container

site_2 (site2.com)
 - another nginx container (82:80), another php container

**main_server .conf**

```
server {
    listen          80;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    server_name     site.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://<site_container_ip_address>:82/;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

**site1 .conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

If I try to access site.com:82, it works fine. But in site.com:80 it returns error 504

I run the containers using **docker-compose**

```
version: '3.5'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: testapp
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: testapp
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - testapp-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: testwebserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "82:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - testapp-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  testapp-network:
    driver: bridge
    name: testapp_network
```

Comment: How do you start your Stack? Docker compose? Can you please provide the file if so? Is your App running on port 9000?

Comment: I don't see the main nginx service in your `docker-compose`. Can you provide that as well?

Comment: One issue I see is that your `ports:` config for your `webserver` is saying to map port `80` of the nginx container to port `82` of the host. I think you probably want this to read `"80:80"`. I recently did something very similar with a set of WordPress sites. Feel free to explore this if it is helpful: https://github.com/collinbarrett/wp-host-on-containers

Comment: hello guys, thank you for replying. I just solve by just removing the port in proxy pass. proxy_pass  http://<site_container_ip_address>, just the ip address of the container.

thank you so much for your help